# How to implement a time dependent exponential function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

[image: Equation]

This is the equation I am trying to implement. I am using Simulink integrator block and simple algebraic blocks for it. How can I implement the last part `(t-tk)` because I don't know how to use the simulation `time(t)` in simulink.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Specifically, we would like to see your code (blocks in this case) and your attempt on including `time(t)`. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: You can use the clock block to get time